# Bootstrap 3 - open modal from another modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

Is it possible in **Bootstrap 3** to **open modal from another modal**? I have modal windows with content loaded from external html files.

1. I'm opening the modal window. There I have a form to submit.
2. After clicking the submit button I would like to go to the next step with a new modal window (and a new content from another html file).

As far as I know you can't have two modal windows simultaneously, so I have to close the first modal and then open the second one. The problem is I have to do after clicking the submit button in the first modal.

I've tried to use the `data-dismiss="modal"` with `data-toggle="modal"` attributes on the submit button but they only hide the first modal, the background in still dark and nothing happens.

Comment: There is a `data-target` attribute, have you used that? .. try adding `data-target='#(id of the modal div)'` to the close button.

Comment: I have it. Button looks like this: `<button class="uploadSection__addBox col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" href="upload1b.html" data-target=".popModal">`

Comment: try using id instead of class `.popModal`

Comment: I guess, you have to manually close then.

Comment: Is it possible to fire modal window without clicking on element and passing data attributes?

Comment: Yes.. `$("...").modal('show');`or `$("...").modal('hide');` check here - http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-usage

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you can use http://jschr.github.io/bootstrap-modal/bs3.html for that; check stackable example.